# Passing and returning 2d arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am new to c++ and I have written this piece of c++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int** mat_mult(int mat1[2][2], int mat2[2][2]){
    int mat3[2][2] = {{0,0},{0,0}};
    for(int i(0);i<2;i++){
        for(int j(0);j<2;j++){
            for(int k(0);k<2;k++){
                mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][k]*mat2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return mat3;
}

int** mat_pow(int mat[2][2], int n){
    int mat1[2][2] = {{1,0},{0,1}};
    while(n){
        if(n%2==1){
            mat1 = mat_mult(mat, mat1);
        }
        mat = mat_mult(mat,mat);
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return mat1;
}

int specialFib(int n){
    int mat[2][2] = {{0,1},{2,1}};
    mat = mat_pow(mat,n);
    return (mat[0][0]*2 + mat[0][1]);
}

int main(){
    cout << specialFib(3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But compiling this gives me this error,

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int** mat_mult(int (*)[2], int (*)[2])':
prog.cpp:13: error: cannot convert 'int (*)[2]' to 'int**' in return
prog.cpp: In function 'int** mat_pow(int (*)[2], int)':
prog.cpp:20: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int**' to 'int [2][2]'
prog.cpp:22: error: cannot convert 'int**' to 'int (*)[2]' in assignment
prog.cpp:25: error: cannot convert 'int (*)[2]' to 'int**' in return
prog.cpp: In function 'int specialFib(int)':
prog.cpp:30: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int**' to 'int [2][2]'
```

I tried to find any solution, but no luck. :(

Answer (score 2):

```
int **mat3 = {{0,0},{0,0}};
```

This makes `mat3` a pointer to a pointer to an integer. You can initialize it to any pointer to a pointer to an integer you want. But `{{0,0},{0,0}}` is an array, not a pointer to a pointer to an integer.

Perhaps you want:

```
int mat3[2][2] ...
```

Comment: Updated the code - some other errors !! :( check the OP.

Comment: Since `mat1` ceases to exist once `mat_pow` returns, returning a pointer to it makes no sense anyway. If you're going to return a pointer, you have to decide who is responsible for allocating that memory and who is responsible for freeing it. In this case, rather than returning a pointer, you probably want to caller to pass in a pointer to the place it wants the answer to go. (Or use real C++ types instead of these C types.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically allocate your 2d array then your code should look like that:

```
int** mat3 = new int*[2];
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
  mat3[i] = new int[2];
```

and then deallocation:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    delete [] mat3[i];
}
delete [] mat3;
```

also you must manually initialize its values

---

as in other answers, I would never use such dynamic arrays, but vector of vectors

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this question C++ so use C++!
You can either use `std::array<std::array<int,Xsize>, Ysixe>>` if you know both sizes at compile time or `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, arrays are very special collection facilities. You should definitely read more about [standard container classes](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) and then write everything new from scratch -- Trust me, it *will* save time! :)

Objects of standard container classes can be returned from a function in the same easy way as primitive types (like `int` or `double`).

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > GetInts()
{
   // ...
   return v;
}
```

Your problem will simply disappear.

Pointers and arrays imply **low-level memory management**; that is certainly not beginners stuff!